# Gradle dependency on source set

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I have a project with 3 source sets. One common, and two dependent on it.

```
sourceSets {
    common {}

    api {
        compileClasspath += common.output
        runtimeClasspath += common.output
    }

    main {
        compileClasspath += common.output
        runtimeClasspath += common.output
    }
}
```

Also i have some dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    commonCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    commonCompile 'io.netty:netty-all:4.0.23.Final'

    ...

    compile 'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:3.1.0'
    compile 'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:3.1.0'
    ...
}
```

Also i have a different project and want to add dependency on `api` source set from first project.

How can i do such thing?

Thanks.

Comment: So the best idea would be to create a separate project named `api` or whatever and build a jar from it and install in dependencies repository. Then specify a dependency pointing to `api` from both projects.

Comment: when you say a "different project" is it still in the scope of a multi-project gradle build? or is it completely external?

Comment: 1) I should use source sets instead of separate modules. Because of 3rd forces >_<    
2) Yes, it's multi-project with 30+ module. One of them - mine. And it has source set. Another module within multi-project need to depend on my `api` source set.